# Max Value for TextInput in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Does anyone know of a way to restrict a user from entering a number over 100 into a textinput field in flex?

i.e. a user can enter any number between and including 0-100 but not 101

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to check it manually, if this is your code

```
<input change='_handleTextChanges(event)' />
```

and this is the callback

```
function _handleTextChanges(evt:Event):void{
     var target:TextInput = evt.currentTarget as TextInput;
     if(!target) return;
     if(parseInt(target.text) > 100){
         Alert.show("You can't enter a number grater than 100");
         target.text = "100";
     }
     if(parseInt(target.text) < 0){
         Alert.show("You can't enter a number smaller than 0");
         target.text = "0";
     }
}
```

I haven't tried it but it should work

Answer (score 5):

Try this, it should give you the results you're looking for - it won't allow you to enter anything out of range and will flag it as invalid (with a nifty tooltip message as well).

The default validator just provides a way to validate the input, but not restrict entry within a range.  The restrict property allows single character matching (but not a range like you're needing.)

This uses them both and some events to handle it for you - very clean and easy to read / change that range as well...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"    
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"     
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"  height="100%" width="100%">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:NumberValidator id="numberValidator" property="text" 
            minValue="0" maxValue="100"  
            source="{inputNumber}" trigger="{inputNumber}" triggerEvent="change" 
            valid   ="inputNumber.toolTip=inputNumber.text;" 
            invalid ="inputNumber.text=inputNumber.toolTip;"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:TextInput id="inputNumber" restrict="0-9"/>

</s:Application>
```

P.s. It might seem like cheating using the tooltip as I have, but the validator will provide it's own tooltip automatically.  If you don't like that, you can stick it in another static var - I did it this way because of the validator provided tool tip as stated above and to keep it clean.

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

1. Use a [NumericStepper](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/NumericStepper.html) and specify the [maximum](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/NumericStepper.html#maximum) property. 
   With a custom spark skin you could even remove the up and down
   arrows to make it act like a TextInput.
2. Listen for the [keyUp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3akeyUp) or [keyDown](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3akeyDown) events and write your own
   validation to prevent the user from typing numbers greater than 100.
   You could tie this to a [NumericValidator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/validators/NumberValidator.html).